# Chromium keeps crashing with SIGSEGV and reinstallation with ~/.config/chromium deletion does not resolve the issue

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos, chromium

Chromium (Version 94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) Fedora Project (64-bit)) on CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105 worked perfectly well but since last week started to keep crashing randomly with SIGSEGV (sometimes tabs, sometimes the entire browser)
Tried to

```
sudo yum remove chromium
rm -r ~/.config/chromium 
sudo yum install chromium
```

But that did not help.
Is there any other place where chromium keeps its faulty settings which cause it to crash?

EDIT: if I run Chromium from console, every time a tab crashes, this line gets printed:

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset of the browser? `chrome://settings/reset`

Comment: Tried that now and that did not help either, it keeps crashing

Comment: Removing its configuration in /etc ?  But you may want to run a memory check on your system first.

Comment: Try running `chromium-browser --disable-gpu`, in case the problem is with the graphics. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @gerard-h-pille, thied that and no, it does not help

Comment: @harrymc, I am afraid running chromium-browser --disable-gpu does not help

Comment: Might be a problem with the `FONTCONFIG` environment variable. It usually is initialized as `export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts`. Check if its current value is right.

Comment: @harrymc, tried that too but no luck I am afraid

Comment: Any more ideas?